# regex breakdown for "find and replace nth occurrence"

Tags: regex, vim

[I'm analyzing a regex pattern I found on a separate question on the VI SE site](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7421/replace-nth-occurrence-using-substitute), and I'm having trouble breaking it down, i.e.:

```
\(.\{-}\zsPATTERN\)\{N}
```

How does this pattern do a replace operation on the `N`th occurrence of `PATTERN` (i.e. could someone please help me expand the logic in this regex)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the pattern matches N occurrences of a sequence of any 0+ chars, as few as possible, omitting this sequence and then matching the `PATTERN`.

That is:

- `\(` - start of a grouping construct
- `.\{-}` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\zs` - omits the text matched so far
- `PATTERN` - some `PATTERN`
- `\)` - end of the grouping construct
- `\{N}` - a range / limiting quantifier, repeating the group pattern(s) N times.

Comment: I have no idea if there is an online regex tester for Vim, so, [here is a translation to a PCRE regex](https://regex101.com/r/YIYvuw/1) demo.